# How to add text labels to a numerical x axis in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using scatter chart type with a type spline to create a curve for a one series of data. The other series contains one value that will always fall on some point along the curve. At the moment my x-axis is numbered from 0 to 4 which is as it should be. However the numbers on the x-axis such as 0-1 represent an area of business and I would like to show the names of the areas along the x-axis rather than the numbers.

I've attached an image that should illustrate what I'm aiming for.
Is there anyway to achieve this in Highcharts?

```js
$(function() {
  var final_score = 3.2

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Industry Index',
      margin: 30,
      style: {
        fontSize: '14px'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      scatter: {
        lineWidth: 2
      },
      line: {
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    },
    /*yAxis: {
     tickInterval: 1,
    },*/
    xAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 4,
      type: 'number',
      tickInterval: 1
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Industry benchmark',
      data: [
        [0.5, 3],
        [1.5, 6.9],
        [2.5, 9.5],
        [3.5, 16.5]
      ],
      type: 'spline'
      // fillColor: 'rgba(252,96,18,0.8)'
    }, {
      name: 'Your Organisation',
      marker: {
        enabled: true,
        radius: 6
      },
      data: [
        [final_score, 14.05]
      ],
      type: 'spline'
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1em;
  background: #fff;
}

#xaxis {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#xaxis p {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps you

```js
$(function() {
  var final_score = 3.2

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Industry Index',
      margin: 30,
      style: {
        fontSize: '14px'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      scatter: {
        lineWidth: 2
      },
      line: {
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    },
    /*yAxis: {
     tickInterval: 1,
    },*/
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['area1','area2','area3','area4']
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Industry benchmark',
      data: [
        [0.5, 3],
        [1.5, 6.9],
        [2.5, 9.5],
        [3.5, 16.5]
      ],
      type: 'spline'
      // fillColor: 'rgba(252,96,18,0.8)'
    }, {
      name: 'Your Organisation',
      marker: {
        enabled: true,
        radius: 6
      },
      data: [
        [final_score, 14.05]
      ],
      type: 'spline'
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1em;
  background: #fff;
}

#xaxis {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#xaxis p {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```